# Cannot setup Windows XP

Tags: windows, drivers

When I started the computer, I saw this error:

> "Windows cannot start because this file is missing : windows / system
>   / config . Put the original Windows XP setup CD in hard disk then
>   press R to repair system.

And the problem is when I wanted to install Windows or repair it, I receive the following message:

> Make sure any hard disk drives are powered on and properly connected
>   to your computer, and that any disk-related hardware configuration is
>   correct. This may involve running a manufacturer-supplied diagnostic
>   or setup program.
>
> Setup cannot continue. To quit Setup, press F3.

How can I get around this problem and complete installation of Windows XP?

Answer (score 2):

Check in the `BIOS` setting `SATA` mode should be `IDE`.
If not put it to `IDE`, save and exit.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Why should it be set to IDE?  Why not use the proper storage controller drivers instead?

Comment: Yeah most important drivers too.

Comment: well how can i do that ? when i press on sata mode there are : disable - auto - enhanced - combained - non combained .

Comment: so how can i do that ? can u give me the address in bios setup ? and when i press on sata mode there are : disable - enable - auto - enhanced - combained - non combained . and there is no ide mode ! which one do i have to choose ? plz help me more ...

Comment: Make sure your BIOS is set the same as outlined for SATA mode= Enhanced.

Answer (score 1):

Possible hard drive failure or controller failure  Check cables and assure all are tight.  Possbly move to another port to test.

Comment: i,ve tried that but no good results !

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your HDD is functional. Boot the computer and feel the hard drive simultaneously: can you feel the drive spinning up? If not, your hard drive is either dead or isn't receiving power. From there you can do voltage testing.